# Multi platform ASCII spinner in C

Tags: c, console

Okay I've just finished writing a nice tiny C program to have an ASCII spinner (works on Windows and POSIX). I'm quite new to C, so any suggestions would be great. This is designed to be a small function in my other programs, so please point out anything that could cause problems when been integrated into a larger program.

The only part I am not 100% sure about is how I handle the standard output buffer when it's printed the next character in the cycle. I don't want the buffer to fill up with invisible backspace characters, so is using `fflush` on `stdout` the best way?

```
#ifdef _WIN32
    #include <windows.h>
    #define sleepThr(x) Sleep(x)
#else
    #include <unistd.h>
    #define sleepThr(x) usleep((x) * 1000)
#endif

#include <stdio.h>

#define INTERVAL 200

int main()
{
    int counter = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        switch (counter)
        {
            case 0:
                printf("\b|");
                break;

            case 1:
                printf("\b/");
                break;

            case 2:
                printf("\b-");
                break;

            case 3:
                printf("\b\\");
                counter = -1;
                break;
        }

        fflush(stdout);

        sleepThr(INTERVAL);

        counter++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `fflush` is pretty much required as output would otherwise be buffered until a newline character is printed.

You could use `counter` as an index to a character array instead of a big clunky repetitive switch. If you have a `char *spinner = "|/-\\";`, `spinner[0]` will be "|", `spinner[1]` will be "/", etc.

`char *spinner = "|/-\\"; printf("\b%c", spinner[counter]);` is going to print the common backspace character and the correct "spinner symbol" for each value of `counter`.  The `spinner` variable does not need to be declared because it's a string literal: `printf("%c", "|/-\\"[counter]);` can be used instead.

Apart from the unnecessary `switch`, I'd say you have an excessive amount of blank lines. If they are used more scarcely, their relative effect will be greater. Readability becomes more important as the program gets bigger.

```
/*
 * Separated groups of code:
 * If there were empty lines between all statements, it would be
 * difficult to tell the groups apart.
 */

foo(bar->baz);
foo(bar->quux);

counter++;
counter %= 4;
```

## Here's a modified version:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
    #include <windows.h>
    #define sleepThr(x) Sleep(x)
#else
    #include <unistd.h>
    #define sleepThr(x) usleep((x) * 1000)
#endif

#include <stdio.h>

#define INTERVAL 200

int main()
{
    int counter;
    while (1)
    {
        for (counter = 0; counter < 4; counter++)
        {
            printf("\b%c", "|/-\\"[counter]);
            fflush(stdout);
            sleepThr(INTERVAL);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```